# Show all triggers in a MySQL database

Tags: sql, mysql, database, triggers, sqlcommand

What is the command to list all triggers in a MySQL database?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

The command for listing all triggers is:

```
show triggers;
```

or you can access the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` table directly by:

```
select trigger_schema, trigger_name, action_statement
from information_schema.triggers
```

- You can do this from version 5.0.10 onwards.
- More information about the [`TRIGGERS` table is here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers-table.html).

Comment: I'd recommend going with using the "SHOW TRIGGERS" query instead of accessing information_schema directly - the latter will be very slow once you have more than thousand databases on the server while "SHOW TRIGGERS" still has an outstanding performance.

Comment: Thanks fpr second "complicated" version. The first doesn't work (don't know the resion) on one of hosts ...

Comment: Note that `SHOW TRIGGERS` requires that you have the `TRIGGER` privilege for that database and table. If you login to MySQL with an unprivileged user, executing `SHOW TRIGGERS` will return nothing instead of throwing an error. That can be confusing if you aren't aware of the privilege requirement.

Answer (score 18):

I hope following code will give you more information.

```
select * from information_schema.triggers where 
information_schema.triggers.trigger_schema like '%your_db_name%'
```

This will give you total 22 Columns in **MySQL version: 5.5.27** and Above

```
TRIGGER_CATALOG 
TRIGGER_SCHEMA
TRIGGER_NAME
EVENT_MANIPULATION
EVENT_OBJECT_CATALOG
EVENT_OBJECT_SCHEMA 
EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE
ACTION_ORDER
ACTION_CONDITION
ACTION_STATEMENT
ACTION_ORIENTATION
ACTION_TIMING
ACTION_REFERENCE_OLD_TABLE
ACTION_REFERENCE_NEW_TABLE
ACTION_REFERENCE_OLD_ROW
ACTION_REFERENCE_NEW_ROW
CREATED 
SQL_MODE
DEFINER 
CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT
COLLATION_CONNECTION
DATABASE_COLLATION
```

Comment: I'd avoid using `LIKE` when dealing with schema. I've worked in environments where doing it that way would be error prone where a client had a database named "company" and another named "company_project". I'd also suggest capitalising KEYWORDS for clarity and INFORMATION_SCHEMA and the columns there so it's clear you're not dealing with a regular DB.

Answer (score 13):

You can use below to find a particular trigger definition.

```
SHOW TRIGGERS LIKE '%trigger_name%'\G
```

or the below to show all the triggers in the database. It will work for MySQL 5.0 and above.

```
SHOW TRIGGERS\G
```

Answer (score 11):

For showing a particular trigger in a particular schema you can try the following:

```
select * from information_schema.triggers where 
information_schema.triggers.trigger_name like '%trigger_name%' and 
information_schema.triggers.trigger_schema like '%data_base_name%'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySQL Workbench:
Connect to the MySQL Server
Select DB

- tables
- on the table name line click the edit icon (looks like a work tool)
- in the table edit window - Click the tab "Triggers"
- on the Triggers list click th eTrigger name to get its source code

Answer (score 1):

```
USE dbname;
SHOW TRIGGERS
```

OR

```
SHOW TRIGGERS FROM dbname;
```

Answer (score 0):

This sentence could contribute to solving the problem:

```
select LOWER(concat('delimiter |', '\n', 'create trigger %data_base_name%.', TRIGGER_NAME, '\n', 
'    ', ACTION_TIMING, ' ', EVENT_MANIPULATION, ' on %data_base_name%.', EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE, ' for each row', '\n',
ACTION_STATEMENT, '\n',
'|')) AS TablaTriggers from information_schema.triggers where 
information_schema.triggers.trigger_schema like '%data_base_name%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show all triggers with the SQL below. *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-triggers-table.html) explains `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS` table and I recommend to use [\G](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html) which can show them more clearly and the SQL below can show more details than [SHOW TRIGGERS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-triggers.html) which I explain last:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS;
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS\G
```

And, you can show the triggers of `apple` database with the SQL below:

```sql
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS WHERE TRIGGER_SCHEMA = 'apple';
```

And, you can show the triggers of `apple` database selecting `apple` database with [USE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/use.html#:%7E:text=The%20USE%20statement%20tells%20MySQL,or%20some%20object%20within%20it.&text=The%20database%20name%20must%20be%20specified%20on%20a%20single%20line.). *[The doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-triggers.html) explains `SHOW TRIGGERS` and I recommend to use `\G` which can show them more clearly:

```sql
USE apple;
SHOW TRIGGERS;
```

Or:

```sql
USE apple;
SHOW TRIGGERS\G
```

Or:

```sql
USE apple;
SHOW TRIGGERS FROM apple;
```

Or:

```sql
USE apple;
SHOW TRIGGERS FROM apple\G
```

And, you can show the triggers of `orange` database even if selecting `apple` database with `USE`:

```sql
USE apple;
SHOW TRIGGERS FROM orange;
```

And, you can show the triggers of `apple` database not selecting any one of databases with `USE`:

```sql
SHOW TRIGGERS FROM apple;
```

Be careful, if you run the SQL below not selecting any one of databases with `USE`:

```sql
SHOW TRIGGERS;
```

Then, there is the error below:

> ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected