# Mysql create trigger if not exist

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a script that creates triggers,
I would like to run it multiple times and if a trigger already exist it needs to skip the creation part.

Is there a "create if not exist" in mysql triggers?

EDIT:

I tried :

```
    IF NOT EXISTS ((SELECT TRIGGER_NAME
        FROM information_schema.triggers
        WHERE TRIGGER_SCHEMA = 'xxx_admin' AND TRIGGER_NAME = 'test_AFTER_UPDATE')) 
        THEN
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `xxx_admin`.`test_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `test` FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO auditTest 
        select *, now() from test where id = NEW.id;
        END;
  END IF;
```

I get : syntex error " 'IF' is not valid input at this location

Comment: No, there isn't. Is there are reason to not use both `DROP TRIGGER` and `CREATE TRIGGER`?

Comment: this will result in information lost

Comment: `select trigger_name from information_schema.triggers where trigger_schema like '%your_db_name%'` Fetch result of this query into varibale. If varible is null then go normal else skip trigger creation part.

Comment: @lior, what Information will use lose? Lock the table if you are afraid that trigger might be not fire due to DROP/CREATE.

Comment: @NagendraNigade I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

To check a trigger exist or not use following

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.triggers
where trigger_schema = 'schema_name'
and trigger_name = 'triggername'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers-table.html) for existing triggers (credits to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47363/how-do-you-list-all-triggers-in-a-mysql-database)):

```
SELECT trigger_schema, trigger_name, action_statement
    FROM information_schema.triggers
```

If a particular `trigger` is existing, you can then skip creating it:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS WHERE TRIGGER_SCHEMA = 'your_schema' AND TRIGGER_NAME = 'your_trigger_name'))
    CREATE TRIGGER ...
```

Comment: I tried this but I get " 'IF' (if) is not valid input at this position