# MySQL disconnects on non-SELECT statements with a specific table

Tags: mysql, docker, disconnect

I am getting disconnects when trying to run non-SELECT statements against a specific table in a mysql database.  Running SELECT statements encounters no issues, but simple INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements result in the client hanging for a short period (10-20 seconds) before disconnecting.  This is happening with multiple client types (mysql CLI, mysqlworkbench, appsmith).  From what I can tell, the other tables in the database don't have this problem.  This table has less than 200 records in it and was working just fine for months before this started happening.

The mysql general log doesn't provide any clues - it just shows the query statement coming in, and then the reconnection after the disconnection.  I'm not sure where else to focus my troubleshooting.  Any ideas?

Have tried simple statements using multiple clients against this table (bad) as well as other tables (good).  Have restarted mysql docker container.  Have tailed general log while performing these actions.

Comment: Check if there are any triggers that are causing any issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47363/how-do-you-list-all-triggers-in-a-mysql-database

Comment: No triggers in entire database:   mysql> show triggers;
Empty set (0.01 sec)